# How to get all tracklog of member in club (with name athlete and time start every run) Strava through API V3

Tags: .net, rest, web-services, c#-4.0, strava-api-v3

I write a service get data from club Strava for Running Club. I want show on dashboard with some infor like that: fullname, distance, moving_time, elapsed_time, time start tracklog, ...
I call api `api/v3/clubs/{id_club}/activities` data response have fullname of athlete but not have time start tracklog
When I call `api/v3/athletes/{id_strava_member_in_club}/activities` data respone with full infor I need, but only return data of my ID. With other member it response Not allowed to view unauthenticated activities.
Some body had already work with Strava API V3 can help solution call with another member.
Many thank for your support.

When call api get all tracklog in club `api/v3/clubs/{id_club}/activities`:
It return

> {
> "resource_state": 2,
> "athlete": {
> "resource_state": 2,
> "firstname": "a",
> "lastname": "a"
> },
> "name": "Morning Football (Soccer)",
> "distance": 6290.6,
> "moving_time": 3109,
> "elapsed_time": 4015,
> "total_elevation_gain": 0.0,
> "type": "Run",
> "sport_type": "Run",
> "workout_type": 0
> }
> Follow this it missing Time start of tracklog.

When call api get tracklog off `api/v3/athletes/{id_of_strava}/activities` it return data

> {
> "resource_state": 2,
> "athlete": {
> "id": ccc,
> "resource_state": 1
> },
> "name": "Morning Run",
> "distance": 15007.2,
> "moving_time": 4434,
> "elapsed_time": 4448,
> "total_elevation_gain": 5.9,
> "type": "Run",
> "sport_type": "Run",
> "workout_type": null,
> "id": 10271342378,
> "start_date": "2023-11-23T21:49:26Z",
> "start_date_local": "2023-11-24T04:49:26Z",
> "timezone": "(GMT+07:00) Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
> "average_speed": 3.385,
> "max_speed": 4.63,
> "average_cadence": 90.8,
> }
> Follow this, it ok for my ID Strava but I call with another ID it return `Not allowed to view unauthenticated activities`